# EXT:Form TYPO3 form finisher settings not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions, typo3-form

I created a contact form with an 'email to recipient'-finisher but when the user sends the form, the message "Oops, an error occurred!" show up. However, when I use 'confirmation message' as a finisher no such error shows up. The 'page redirect'-finisher also returns an error.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this? (I'm also not getting anymore detailed error information even though I have the debug mode turned on in the configuration presets..)

Comment: You should set [displayErrors](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/ErrorAndExceptionHandling/Configuration/Index.html) in LocalConfiguration.php to get a more meaningful error message.

Comment: I have, it is set to 1, but I still only get “Oops an error occurred”

Comment: Try to set `config.contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0` in your TypoScript setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not correctly configured the 'Mail handling settings' found under 'Configuration presets' in 'Settings'. I added custom settings to write the form replies to a local file, as the website was not live and I wanted to run tests.